# LAMP Environment for a mac

Tags: php, xampp, lamp

I'm currently using XAMMP for mac (http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html) for development, however this package hasn't been updated over a year. I'm running into some issues because my development environment is different version older than our production servers.

Does anyone has recommendation for a XAMMP replacement or how to update xammp with the latest software, especially the PHP  5.4 module.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=lamp+for+mac&qscrl=1 not even googled, right?

Comment: specifically what in the package is an older version than your production server (apache, mysql, or php)?  or more importantly, what version of which component do you *need*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the apache friends website and the mac installation is up to date.

I use a mac at work with xampp and it works perfectly well using PHP 5